# modify relationship in instagram by using oriceon laravel 5 oauth wrapper

Tags: api, oauth, laravel-5, instagram-api

Iam using [oriceon/oauth-5-laravel](https://github.com/oriceon/oauth-5-laravel) for connecting with **instagram**.I authenticated and i got my name and id by through this request

`$result = json_decode($instagramService->request('users/self'), true);`
Now i want to follow a person by using this [oriceon/oauth-5-laravel](https://github.com/oriceon/oauth-5-laravel).
How i could post the request to follow a person by using this .

**NOTE:**dont refer the instagram developer page.I reffred it a lot.But i couldnt put a post request for ORICEON/laravel oauth wrapper for instagram.

HELP ME.TYSM in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this .Copy this method to your controller and do proper routing.

```
public function followWithInstagram(Request $request)
    {
        $instagram_id='id of the user that you want to follow';
        $code = $request->get('code');
        $instagramService = \OAuth::consumer('Instagram');
        if ( ! is_null($code))
        {
            $state = isset($_GET['state']) ? $_GET['state'] : null;
            $instagramService->requestAccessToken($code, $state);
            $linkData = [
              'action' =>'follow',
                          ];
            $result =json_decode($instagramService->request('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'.$instagram_id.'/relationship','POST',$linkData),true);
            if(!$result){
                return ("Failed");
            }
            else {
                return ("SUCCESS");         
            }
        } else {
            $url = $instagramService->getAuthorizationUri();
            return redirect((string)$url);
        } 
    }
```